# Delete woocommerce customer sessions and transients automatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

One of my client's site was slowed down too much and its waiting time was 6 to 7 seconds. I found the root cause which was because the `wp_options table` was filled with a lot of customer sessions data that increased table size to 1.7 GB. It took 6-7 hours to delete 2 million rows. I know I can now delete sessions and transients manually by going to `Woocomerce > System Status > Tools > Clear all` sessions & Clear transients but I want it to be done automatically after one or two days. Is there anything could be done like creating `cron job` etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try this plugin:

[Delete Expired Transients](https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-expired-transients/)

Comment: This plugin has an option to remove obsolete sessions from WooCommerce version 2.4 and earlier—something WP-Optimize does not offer. I had 18,816 such rows. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

long time later but that awnser will can help someone

below the code will execute every day (from your current time), the clean session/cart Woocommerce.

```
// clean cart every day
if (!wp_next_scheduled('cron_wc_clean_cart')) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cron_wc_clean_cart' );
}

add_action ( 'cron_wc_clean_cart', 'wc_clean_session_cart' );
function wc_clean_session_cart() {
    global  $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "TRUNCATE {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key='_woocommerce_persistent_cart_" . get_current_blog_id() . "';" );
    wp_cache_flush();
}
```

for transients, its that function in wc:

```
wc_delete_expired_transients()
```